# Как сделать правую колонку в bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Как сверстать с помощью bootstrap правые колонки в ряд не зависимо от левого?

[Такой макет](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzCct.jpg)

[Вот как получаеться](http://codemixru.github.io/)

Answer (score 2):

Для решения вашей задачи достаточно просто использовать колонки. Например так:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- это начало ряда -->
    <div class="col-md-8">
        Здесь блоки первой колонки
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        Здесь блоки второй колонки
    </div>
</div> <!-- это конец ряда -->
```

Comment: у меня в коде так и есть, я не могу сделать в ряд правую колонку не зависимо от левой. [Вот как получаеться](http://codemixru.github.io/)

Comment: @codemix, выложите пример кода, который у вас не работает и напишите ожидаемый результат в вопросе, - мы вам подскажем.

Comment: http://codemixru.github.io/

Comment: Вся первая колонка должна быть размещена в блоке "Здесь блоки первой колонки". Вторая, соответственно в блоке "Здесь блоки второй колонки". У вас сейчас несколько независимых рядов, а вам нужен всего один.

Answer (score 0):

Такой макет получается путем указания классов, соответствущего количеству ячеек сетки. Например левая колонка имеет класс `col-md-3`, средняя `col-md-6`, правая `col-md-3`

Подробнее смотрите [тут](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)